# Restore from Ctrl+X – weird bug

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but I don't know any other. Please point to the correct exchange if any.

I wrote some text in Notepad, I use Windows 7, and by accident I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The problem was that when I paste, it pasted the last thing I copied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
I haven't saved the document, so there is any way to restore or find what was cut the last time?

I know that Notepad is minimalist. I read other posts, but I just want to make sure that is destroyed forever.

Comment: This needs editing. As it is it makes no sense.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL-Z ?

Comment: What bug?  (As oldmud0 asks, do you not know that Ctrl+X is the keyboard shortcut for “Cut”?)  You just want to make sure that ***what*** is destroyed forever? … … … … … … … … … (Sorry; I didn’t notice that this was a four-year-old post by a long-gone user.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Notepad is still running in that same session and you haven't made too many edits since cutting it out, you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (undo) to restore the text. You can't view a history of things you cut in a simple program like Notepad. I'm sure that programs like Office have clipboard history.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> deletes your selection *and* copies it to the clipboard at the same time (did you not notice until now?). This is standard behavior that works in any text editor.

If you want it 100% deleted, removed forever from your undo history from every text editor in the face of your monitor, all you have to do is delete it with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (**not** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>), save your work, and reopen your text editor to clear your undo history.